# Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: NoSuchWindowException: Message: Unable to get browser IE

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, robotframework

While executing the test cases on IE, I am getting a warning message:

> Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: NoSuchWindowException: Message: Unable to get browser

the browser opens fine,

I only get this issue when im doing the test on IE, on chrome and firefox 
there's no issue,

Can you please assist me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Same here, but didn't get any answer yet